# How to make points then add them all up

Tags: java, eclipse, points

I have made a code witch asks you questions and for every question you get right it adds one point, the problem is i want to know how to show your score. Like how many points you have all together.

```
System.out.println("#1: What is 8+8?");
answer=in.nextInt();
if (answer == 16)           
    System.out.println("Correct!");
else
    System.out.println("Incorrect!");
if (answer == 16)
    points =+ 1;
```

That is an example showing that if the "answer" is correct it will +1 point. I would like for when it tells you it is correct how many points you have. Example: "Correct! You now have "points" point(s)!
Here are my ints if you need them

```
int points;
int answer2;
int answer;
```

I only have 2 questions so far because i am waiting for this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a counter variable that will hold the number of correct answers.

```
Integer scoreCount = 0; //initial score

if (answer == 16) {
    scoreCount += 1; //increase score count           
    System.out.println("Correct! You now have " + scoreCount + " points"); //show latest score
}
```

Comment: Oh man thanks! That other guys answer worked but i could not figure out how to hold the number! Thanks sooo much!

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println("Correct! You now have "+points+" points!");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was something like that just didn't know exactly.

Comment: No problem! It would be great if you could mark me as the answer to your question. :)